# PhoneGap for mobile application

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, blackberry, mobile

Is PhoneGap tool is good for developing mobiles applications? Suppose I am developing iPhone, Android, Windows, Blackberry, etc mobile application development in that case we can use Phonegap or not?

Comment: "PowerGap"? Do you mean PhoneGap?

Comment: Yes, you can use PhoneGap (Cordova) to create applications for all the platforms you mention. Yes, it is a good platform for developing mobile applications. You need to be more specific in your requirements to know if it is appropriate for your scenario though.

Comment: @MattLacey: Actually my requirement is that if any one of my big client requires a iphone or android mobile aap for him/her software in that case we can use PhoneGap or not? and How we can know that any mobile app is build in PhoneGap or in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be based on your requirements. Cross-platform environments have lots of bugs and issues. 
Most likely developers used them to create application that does not need a lot of processing and threads and does not need the heavy use of the hardware like an application to browse a web content with a nice views like HTML's.

I use Sencha and PhoneGap before for such application.

Comment: actually I'm using sencha throw phoneGap ! I don't have any idea which is robust more

Answer (score 0):

I use jembe (http://www.jembe.fr). It also let you develop and build your iphone/android application from windows or linux, and give you an API to access native features.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily PhoneGap was developed to permit cross plaform development ( i.e code once and compile for various mobile platform supported by PhoneGap). This is  good when your application do not require several hardware feature, multitasking or concurrency implementations.
One major disadvantage is that some PhoneGap api will work well for some platform and will have Quirks on other platforms, so you have to properly check if the  feature you want to use works well for all platforms you want to develop for.
I will conclude by saying that every thing depends on your app requirements